# Axios Post Not Connecting to Backend with correct url not getting errors

Tags: node.js, reactjs

This is the front-end react js application. I am trying to connect to the back end but I am not getting the data to post.

```
  const addPerson =  () => {

   axios.post(
        'http://localhost:3002/api/create',

        {
          first: "Kevin",
          last: "Buter",
          phone: "313",
          email: "k@gmail.com",
        },{
            headers: headers
        }
      )
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
        console.log(response.status);
      })
      .catch((error) => console.log(error));

 
  };
```

This is the back end. The back-end code is written in node js and express.

```
// Route for creating the post
app.post('/api/create', (req, res) => {
  const firsts = req.body.first;
  const lasts = req.body.last;
  const phones = req.body.phone;
  const emails = req.body.email;

  db.query(
    'INSERT INTO users (first, last, email,phone) VALUES (?,?,?,?)',
    [firsts, lasts, emails, phones],
    (err, result) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
      console.log(result);
    }
  );
});
```

What can I do to get the code to connect and post the data to the database?

I tried to get the front-end react application to connect to the back-end node application. I have researched adding different headers and changing the data structure by storing it as a variable rather than a json object. I have also used postman to test the post url on the back-end with sample data and the data posted.

Comment: You are not sending anything back from the server

Comment: What headers are you using in your client code `{ headers: headers }`? What is your server print to the console after trying to insert data to DB?